# Running shell script with NSTask causes posix_spawn error

Tags: objective-c, macos, shell, posix, nstask

I'm trying to run a shell script with NSTask with the following code:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/Users/username/connect.sh"];
[task launch];
```

But I get `An uncaught exception was raised` and `Couldn't posix_spawn: error 8`

If I just run the script in terminal, everything works.

Here is what the script contains:

```
if [ ! -d ~/Remote/username/projects  ] 
then  
        sshfs -C -p 22 user@remotecomputer.com:/home/username ~/Remote/username        
fi
```

Comment: SourceTree hits the same issue running NSTasks: https://superuser.com/questions/1437788/sourcetree-custom-actions-couldnt-posix-spawn-error-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use setLaunchPath like this:

```
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];
```

Then use setArguments for your script:

```
[task setArguments: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"~/connect.sh", nil]];
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also add `#!/bin/bash` to the start of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d ~/Remote/username/projects  ] 
then  
    sshfs -C -p 22 user@remotecomputer.com:/home/username        ~/Remote/username        
fi
```

Comment: or on newer macOS Versions add

#!/bin/zsh